# Get the enclosed area formed by the four large rectangles

Tags: cgal

I am learning to use CGAL.

As shown in the figure, there are four large rectangles. I used 4 edges for each rectangle to generate the corresponding arrangement through CGAL. I also generated an arrangement with a total of 16 edges from the four rectangles, so I now have 5 arrangements.

From the 5th arrangement, I obtained 9 bounded faces and one unbounded face. The face I want is the one labeled as number 5, which is the enclosed area formed by the four large rectangles. How can I find the face I want from the arrangement?

I have tried converting each face in the arrangement into a polygon, and then using `CGAL::do_intersect` to check for intersections with the four large rectangles separately. It's clear that the 5th face does not intersect with any of the four large rectangles, but due to floating point precision issues (I'm using the `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`), the intersection check always fails.

Do you have any feasible suggestions?

[image: arrangement]

Comment: First, once you constructed the 4 arrangements, you can overlay them all and obrain the 5th arrangement. Use the overlay() free function to overlay pairs of arrangements; so, you need to apply it 3 times. Second, there are several ways I can think of to obtain the middle arrangement: 1. Calculate the midpoint of each of the 4 rectangles, then calculate the midpoint, say p, of the 4 midpoints, finally, use point location to obtain the cell that contains p. 2. Use an observer to track the construction of new faces.